# How do I consume custom type definitions for an npm module?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.2

I have written type definitions for the npm package `react-sortable-tree`. I am unable to figure how I should consume it. Here's what I have tried.

I named the definition file `react-sortable-tree/index.d.ts` (following directions given in [Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html)) and added the filename to my `tsconfig.json`. The Typescript compiler (version 2.2.1) could not find the module's definition. I tried both [module resolution methods](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) `Classic` and `Node` without success.

After renaming the file as `react-sortable-tree.d.ts`, the compiler recognized the file with resolution method `Classic`. However, there are other modules that come with type definition files included with the npm package (for example, `redux`), and the compiler fails to find the definition for these packages.

When using the resolution method `Node`, the compiler finds type definitions for all packages, except the one that I have defined. For the `react-sortable-tree` package, the compiler resolves the path to the actual Javascript file that comes with the package and ignores my definitions. As a result, no type checking happens.

How do I write my definition, where do I place it, and what compiler options should I specify so that that compiler considers my type definitions?

Comment: After reading the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) further, I realized that I could create a directory named `node_modules`, put my definition in there and get the compiler to resolve to it. I tried and it works. Is it okay to have a directory named `node_modules` that is not managed by `npm`?

Comment: there shouldnt be a need for creating your own node_modules folder no, and Id recommend against it just in case you WILL use node_modules later.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my setup for a declaration file for the npm module `jison`:

tsconfig:

```
"include": [
    "./src/definitions/jison.d.ts",
    "./src/index.ts"
 ]
```

./src/definitions/jison.d.ts:

```
declare module Jison
{
    export class Parser {
        constructor(grammar:any);
        generate():string;
        parse(program:string):any;
    }
}
declare module "jison"
{
    export = Jison;
}
```

Comment: Have you specified a `resolutionMethod` in your `tsconfig.json`? If unspecified, the resolution method is `Classic` which leads to the compiler not recognizing definitions for package like `redux` which come with their own definitions (that's the behavior that I am seeing).

Comment: Any idea how to include it in an angular project?